# Hiding Fields Depending on User Selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to hide options  within a select  field depending on a user's answer? With Javascript/jQuery.

I have quite a complicated, and long-form, and I want to try avoiding making loads of HTML elements if possible as the conditional logic will just get really confusing.

So the user would follow something similar to this:
1. Step one: select colour (red, blue, green, orange).
2. Step two: select a number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Different numbers shown depending on colour selected in first field.
3. Step three: button displays with a link off-site, link will be dependent on step one and then step two.

Example of a selection could be:
1. Selected Red (red, blue, green, orange),
2. Selected 1 (only show 1, 2, 3) because of red selection.
3. Link to a Red 1 Product.

Its quite hard to explain so I really hope this makes sense.

Above is just a small portion of the form as an example.

Below is some of my example HTML:

```
<select name="color" class="colour">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<select name="numbers" class="numbers">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I know I can use code similar to this, but then I'll end up having to create loads of different select elements as there are many different options depending on selection in each field.

```
$('.colour').on('change',function(){
if ( $(this).val()=== "red") {
  $(".numbers").show();
}
else {
  $(".numbers").hide();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the options? or just hide them?

Comment: Hide them so it should go a bit like this: Select list > Select List > Select List > Link. The link is dependent on each option is chosen in each select list, and each select list will contain different options depending on the selection before it - but I want to put them all in one element to avoid creating loads of different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function loadBtn(){
   let colour = $(".colour").val();
   let numbers = $(".numbers").val();
   $('.btn').html(colour+" - "+numbers);
   $('.btn').attr("href", "http://yourURL.com/?colour="+colour+"&numbers"+numbers);
}

function loadNumbers(elem){
  let value = $(elem).val();
  let range = $(elem).find("option:selected").attr("numberRange");
  let newRanges = range.split(",").map(num => `<option value="${num}">${num}</option>`).join("");
  $('.numbers').html(newRanges);
}

loadNumbers($(".colour"));
loadBtn();

$('.colour').on('change',function(){
  loadNumbers(this);
  loadBtn();
});

$('.numbers').on('change',function(){
  loadBtn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select name="color" class="colour">
  <option value="red" numberRange="1,2,3">Red</option>
  <option value="blue" numberRange="1,2">Blue</option>
  <option value="green" numberRange="1,2,3,4">Green</option>
  <option value="orange" numberRange="1,2,3,4,5,6">Orange</option>
</select>

<select name="numbers" class="numbers">
</select> 
<a class="btn" href=""></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible then to show a button e.g. If you choose Red, then Number 1 from red show button for red number 1? Hope that makes sense.